# Extract text from HTML based on table column via Shell Script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I need to write a shell script that reads an html file `sample.html` and extracts data from a table column, based on another table column. For example, this is the HTML code:

```
<table style="BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse"
  border="0" bordercolor="#000000"
  cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="200">
  <tr >
    <td class="fontStyleOne" width="30%">
      <div align="left">
      core6690.myserverdomain.com </div>
    </td>
    <td  class="tdfontTwo" width="30%">
      <div class="label-styler" align="left">
      admin</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td class="fontStyleOne" width="30%">
      <div align="left">
      core6691.myserverdomain.com </div>
    </td>
    <td  class="tdfontTwo" width="30%">
      <div class="label-styler" align="left">
      secondary </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr >
    <td  class="fontStyleOne" width="30%">
      <div align="left">
      core6692.myserverdomain.com </div>
    </td>
    <td  class="tdfontTwo" width="30%">
      <div class="label-styler" align="left">
      primary </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Let's say that I want to determine what the URL for "admin" then the result would be core6690.myserverdomain.com; if I my input is "primary" then the output would be "core6692.myserverdomain.com" and so on...

The HTML page has a lot more data, header tags, footer stuff, etc., but the important stuff that I am looking for is placed inside a table with the exact same structure I list in the code... except it has many more rows, not necessarily just 3 as in this example.

I have seen related answers in this site that seg, grep, regular expressions, awk, and other tools however none of them are close enough to what I am looking for... plus I do not have much experience with any of the approaches as to modify and make them fit my needs.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not expect someone to answer, providing a help with bash. You should use perl module for HTML parsing and HTML table extraction for that, really. Theoretically this could be done in bash and sed too, of course, but perl parsing approach with this case would be better, really.

Comment: Thanks Piotr Wadas, however I have a restriction set and I must play by the current scenario.

Comment: Must this be in pure bash, or can you use extra tools?  If not perl, can you use awk?  What about PHP?  Note that any solution that doesn't involve a DOM parser (as in perl or PHP or Python) will be extremely easy to break.  You'll want to make sure that you don't list yourself as the author.  This kind of thing should not go on your C.V.

Comment: Hi @ghoti, thanks for your comments. I understand the implications of limiting the tool-set to just bash or pre-compiled utilities in the OS... and about the author/CV/etc, they have nothing to do with the question or its context... this question is based on a mere academic-terms challenge.
I could take the path of python, perl, PHP, or even Java, but that's not the point of the question in its current context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#/bin/bash

for i in `cat sample.html | grep '<\/div>' | sed 's/\s\+//'|sed 's/<.*>//'`; do
    if [ $i == $1 ];
    then
        echo $prev
    fi
    prev=$i
done
```

Example of using

```
$ ./filter.sh primary
core6692.myserverdomain.com
```

P.s: format of the sample.html should be exacly you posted here, server and the name shouldends with  tag and starts with whitespace or tab.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, no fancy stuff just a plain simple solution with available tools. Thanks a lot @servn!

Answer (score 4):

My [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) can do that, if you are allowed to use other tools.

With xpath:

```
xidel /tmp/f.html -e "//tr[td[2] = 'admin']/td[1]"
```

or pattern matching:

```
xidel /tmp/f.html -e "<tr><td>{.}</td><td>admin</td></tr>
```

At least that's how it is done for the excerpt you posted, for the larger file it depends on what else is there.

Comment: Wow, that is an awesome tool @BeniBela, thanks for posting about it. I did look into, however I am forced to think in terms of the built-in/available tools of the OS. Cheers!

Comment: Do you have a ppa for it? That would be awesome

Comment: No. I tried to build it on a build server for all linuxes, but it is written in FreePascal+Lazarus, and the server failed to install Lazarus. However, I only use Lazarus to get UTF-8 support, and the new FreePascal has complete UTF-8 support itself, so I could drop Lazarus and try it again with FreePascal alone.